# Remove E-mail headers from Announcements List SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise

The following picture is an e-mail sent by SharePoint announcement, I didn't set this up, but I am trying to remove the "E-mail Headers" section from being sent in the e-mail.

[image]

Looking online it seems that SharePoint uses alerttemplates.xml file to send these e-mails but the file is really big and somewhat confusing. So I am looking for a easier way to control remove it from the e-mail. Using SharePoint Designer, it seems that I found it, but I am not sure where to change the setting so its not included.
[image]

Any help about this subject is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried unchecking the "Add to Default View" at the top of the ribbon and saving it?

Comment: Yes, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(1) Create a copy of the “alerttemplates.xml” file in the
    `{14}\TEMPLATE\XML` folder and name it say `customalerttemplates.xml`.

(2) Open the `customalerttemplates.xml` file in notepad or Visual Studio
    and find the SharePoint library of your choice i.e. DiscussionBoard
    in our case.

(3) Keep scrolling through the alert template definition for this
    library until you find an element named: `<Properties>` This element
    originally has the following text:

[image]

(4) Modify this element to add the fields that you would like the email
    alert to exclude and remove the fields that you would want the email
    alert to include. e.g. below is the representation of the
     element where we exclude the “E-Mail Headers” field and
    include the “ID” field in the email alert text:

[image]

(5) Save the modified `customalerttemplates.xml` file.

(6) Now we need to update our new alert templates' file to the SharePoint Database, so as to replace the default `alerttemplates.xml` file. We will use the below STSADM command to perform this activity:

{14}\BIN>`stsadm -o updatealerttemplates -url "http://servername:18000" -filename "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\XML\customalerttemplates.xml"`

(7) Perform IISRESET.

The above steps will modify the alert template for your specific choice of library (viz. Discussion Board). Now if you trigger an email from SharePoint to be sent to the subscribed users, you will notice that the E-mail Headers field has been removed and the ID field has been added to the text of the email.

Reference: [SharePoint 2010: How to remove "Email Headers" information from alert emails](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2404173)

Comment: The referenced article is very good. Easiest way to work on the alerttemplates.xml file is to use something that can collapse the xml trees for you so you do not get distracted by the queries and format sections. 

Please note that changes made in that file will apply to all alerts sent by the farm (well web service really, but easier to think of it as a farm cause hardly anyone I know runs more than 1 web service in their farm)

Comment: This was really helpful to fix the problem. Thanks

Comment: @MicroSumol You're welcome!