# How to remove "Email To" and "Email Sender" information from alert emails

Tags: custom-alert-templates

I'm writing you because you answered the question in:
[Remove E-mail headers from Announcements List SharePoint 2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/53062/remove-e-mail-headers-from-announcements-list-sharepoint-2010/53630)

THANK YOU very much for the information in that page, it helped me a lot. I removed the EmailHeader of my alert message, but now I need to remove EMAIL TO and SENDER OF THE EMAIL, but I have several doubts:

1) The name of "EMAIL TO" is 
EmailTo or Email_x0020_To or ???
(I tried both and it didn't work)

2) The name of "SENDER OF THE EMAIL" is 
EmailSender or Email_x0020_Sender or ???
(I tried both and it didn't work)

3) For each change in my customalerttemplates.xml file do I need to run stsadm...? or just run IISRESET?

4) Where/how can I use the following line of code:

SPList.Fields[].InternalName?

5) How can I change the URL of the buttons in the message?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved points 1,2 and 3 using 
"EmailTo;Email_x0020To;EmailSender;Email_x0020_Sender;" in  element.

But I still need to know how change the URL of the buttons in the message, could you please help me?

Thank you in advance.